# If anything is connected to pin 39 Pi wont boot

Tags: gpio

Raspberry Pi 3 B+, Raspbian GNU/Linux 11 (bullseye)

I'm doing some DAQ with a stack of [MCC172 hats](https://www.mccdaq.com/DAQ-HAT/MCC-172.aspx). The hats have a trigger to start acquisition but not to stop. So I set up GPIO21 (pin 40) as input that triggers the end of acquisition.

The trigger comes from an Arduino Nano via a potential divider to get 3.3v with GND of my trigger connected to pin 39.

This was working initially but today the Pi wont boot if I have anything connected to pin 39. If I remove the connection everything boots up, add the connection it shuts down.

Anybody any idea why this is happening?

Some additional information, if I connect the common ground to a different GND pin on the Pi header then this disables my DAQ devices but doesnt turn the Pi off.

Schematic:

[image]

Comment: `the Pi wont boot` not at all? nothing on the screen?

Comment: @JaromandaX yep nothing, red LED comes on but no green LED, blank screen, soon as I remove the connector it springs to life

Comment: what are you connecting to that ground pin anyway?

Comment: a common ground between the Nano & the Pi so that the trigger voltage from the voltage divider is referenced properly

Comment: and that stops the pi from booting ... wow ... perhaps it's not what you think it is

Comment: Also, if I connect when the Pi is already running it will shut down & not boot up again until the connection is removed

Comment: @Milliways have added a diagram to the OP to clear things up

Comment: Shouldn't the USB connection already provide a common ground?

Comment: @goldilocks it does but the triggering device wont always be powered by the PI and will eventually be needed trigger a series of processes that dont directly involve the DAQ Pi

Comment: " if I connect the common ground to a different GND pin on the Pi header then this disables my DAQ devices but doesnt turn the Pi off" ALL the Gnd are connected (to the Gnd plane) so presumably your wiring is not what you expect.

Comment: @Milliways yes I now suspect that the MCC hats are doing something they said they didnt do. I've opened the issue with their tech support